# Disable & enable of Index in db2luw

Tags: db2

is it possible to temporarily disable & again enable of an index on a table in db2luw.
If so can some one tell me the syntax or process, to achieve this.

I am updating tons of records . Before that I have to disable all the indexes on all the tables & after that have to create only one user created index (I9) on all the tables. My update query has to be run only with one index(I9).
When once my update query got completed. again I have to reset all the tables to their original position(previous indexes).

I am very new to db2. kindly excuse me if I am wrong at any stage in my question.

That is what I am trying to find.
If you have a better solution for this, can you please let me know.It l be a very good favour.
Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "disable". Do you want to update/insert/delete without a performance hit due to index updates? Do you want to SELECT without respect to an index? Something else? What exactly is the _business problem_ that you're trying to solve? Show an example.

Comment: explanation added to the question.

Comment: Excellent edit. Thank you. Ian's answer for `DROP/CREATE INDEX` fits what you need. It will give practically the same result and performance as 'disable' would.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "disable" an index.  Please see `DROP INDEX <name>` and `CREATE INDEX <name>`.